# Cosa significa "massaira"?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro *Figura gigante* di Nico Orengo ho letto questa frase:

> Lo pregò di attendere sulla panchina di pietra di fronte all’ingresso, a ridosso proprio dei grandi ciuffi di bambú nero, chiedendogli se avrebbe preferito un bicchiere di massaira o vermentino.

Su [Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vermentino) ho trovato che "vermentino" è un tipo di uva e anche il vino che se ne estrae, ma non ho trovato nulla sul vocabolo "massaira". Si tratta anche in questo caso di un vino?

Comment: Non ho tempo per approfondire, ma qui c'è un punto di partenza:
https://books.google.it/books?id=cLRoAAAAMAAJ&q=%22massaira%22&dq=%22massaira%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rBKIVfKBEYupsgGTsKvADw&redir_esc=y

Comment: *Vermentino* è certamente un vino (sardo e ligure, ma anche toscano e basso piemontese); su *massaira* non ho trovato nulla, né l'ho mai sentito. Forse un vino piemontese non diffuso.

Comment: Potrebbe essere un errore di trascrizione e riferirsi a Massafra, in Puglia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In questo [*Intemelion n.11 (2005) - cultura e territorio -  Quaderno di studi dell’Accademia di cultura intemelia*](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj1nNabgNrlAhVNyKQKHSz4CjgQFjADegQIARAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.intemelion.it%2Fpdf%2F11%2F06-carassale.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0-OE1utH4rRd-mD6Z2TqXP) nella sezione DIZIONARIO DEI VITIGNI INTEMELI si può leggere:

> 17. - Massarda B 
>       Sinonimi: **Massaira**, Mortolese, Tabacca Bianca.
>        Storia: la Massarda è uno dei vitigni maggiormente diffusi
>       nell’Imperiese tra la fine dell’Ottocento e la prima metà del
>       Novecento (in particolare a Sanremo; vedi: « La Liguria Agricola », I,
>       1870, n. 10). Nel « Bollettino ampelografico », *Circondario di Porto
>       Maurizio* (cit., *ad vocem*) si legge: « di antica importazione. Poco
>       diffuso (?), ama posizioni elevate e costantemente soleggiate, nei
>       luoghi bassi non viene mai a perfetta maturità. Produce discretamente.
>       Dà vino generoso e facile a conservarsi. Uva serbevole perché avente
>       buccia resistente e coriacea: coltivato in Porto Maurizio, Oneglia,
>       Poggi ». Citato sia nell’opera di G. Cappi (cit., p. 139), che lo
>       trova a Diano Castello, sia nella *Relazione* di A. Bertani (cit., p.
>       320), sia in *Notizie e studi intorno ai vini ed alle uve d’Italia*
>       (cit., p. 844); M. Calvino (S.A.S.S.R., cit.) non manca di tessere le
>       lodi della Massarda per la sua resistenza all’infezione parassitaria.
>       In « L’agricoltura ligure », III, 1903, n. 35, si legge infatti: « le
>       massarde, uniche viti superstiti all’invasione fillosserica e che a
>       causa della loro forza di resistenza sono adoperate con ottimo
>       successo alla ricostruzione dei vigneti fillosserati ». Nei primi due
>       decenni del Novecento è coltivato particolarmente nell’area intemelia,
>       nei centri di Dolceacqua e Apricale (A.S.I., U.T.E., *commissione
>       censuarie*, f. 110), di Vallebona e Ventimiglia (*Ibidem*, f. 111),
>       nonché di Cipressa e Pompeiana (*Ibidem*, f. 110). Confermano il ruolo
>       del vitigno nell’enologia locale sia G. Dalmasso e G. Dell’Olio (cit.,
>       p. 52), sia F. Mazzoli (cit., p. 72).

Quindi ***massaira*** risulta essere sinonimo di *massarda* e si riferisce ad un particolare tipo di vitigno ed anche al vino che da esso si ricava.

Inoltre il riferimento trovato da @DaG riguardante uno scritto su Montale dello stesso Orengo che menziona il termine è plausibile in quanto trattasi di vitigno diffuso in Liguria.

Comment: Non è uno scritto di Montale, è un libro dello stesso Nico Orengo:  https://books.google.com/books/about/Gli_spiccioli_di_Montale.html?id=qg76AAAACAAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y.

Comment: Ok, grazie. Ho corretto.

Comment: Vedo che "massarda" è anche il vino bianco che se ne estrae di questo vitigno: http://www.civiltadelbere.com/massarda-o-tabacca-uva/, https://books.google.es/books?id=EnJ5J5WYZeUC&pg=PA515&lpg=PA515&dq=massarda+vino&source=bl&ots=24FPtCxtwX&sig=ACfU3U1umqEhZfDULB_aEcUmT956AEKRjA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZh-L2_drlAhWaAmMBHW3bDCUQ6AEwCXoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=massarda%20vino&f=false.

Comment: Potresti aggiungerlo alla risposta?

Comment: Aggiunta precisazione

Answer (score 3):

Sembrerebbe essere un vitigno poco noto, che trovo citato solo in un altro libro dello stesso Orengo, *Gli spiccioli di Montale: requiem per un uliveto*:
[image]

e nella silloge di testi di Francesco Biamonti *Scritti e parlati*:
[image]

Purtroppo ho trovato soltanto questi striminziti estratti da Google. Visto che Orengo è piemontese, che lo è il rossese bianco e che lo può essere il vermentino, possiamo ipotizzare che il massaira sia un vitigno bianco che alligna in Piemonte (o un nome alternativo di un vitigno più noto con un nome diverso).

Answer (score 1):

Come già è stato detto molto probabilmente è un errore. Un vino abbastanza conosciuto è quello proveniente dalla cantina "Massaia".
[image: Vino Massaia]

Comment: È possibile, ma personalmente ritengo improbabile che in un testo narrativo si menzioni una specifica cantina anziché una qualità di vino, considerato anche che lo si accosta al vermentino. Per tagliare la testa al toro, sappiamo da quando è in attività questa cantina? *Figura gigante* è del 1984.

Answer (score 0):

Buongiorno a tutti. Suggerisco un altro riferimento letterario nell'impiego di Massaira. Francesco Biamonti in "La fiaba del vino e del cielo", pubblicato sul supplemento de La Stampa "I segreti del gusto" , n. 18, agosto 2000, poi in "Scritti e parlati", Einaudi, pag. 9.
Scrive Biamonti:
(...) "Erano uomini di gioia e di pena. Prendevano dal vino toni fiabeschi. Se la raccontavano.
*Prendi quella bottiglia dallo scaffale più alto. È Massaira*.
Era un vino che veniva dall'aprico, un bianco.
(...)
Non si può insistere col bianco.
Credevano che il bianco, se di Massaira, facesse impazzire perché eccitava l'immaginazione. Il nero invece placava".

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE e grazie della risposta! Questo testo, però, appare anche nella risposta di @DaG.